# Type of floor for a chemistry lab

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm currently building a small chemistry lab and I'm wondering about which type of floor would be the best to use. Currently I'm mainly doing electrochemistry experiments with lithium and other metals. Although my interests might change in the future.

I was thinking about ceramic tiles. Since it's not flameable and unreactive. Are there better types of floor for my application ?

Comment: Here is link that might be useful for you : [Lab Flooring](https://www.multilab.net/blog/choosing-the-right-flooring-for-your-lab)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This helped me to progress in my decision making process.  Still not 100 % sure for what i will decide but i now have a better overview

Comment: Good luck with that! Always willing to help:)